# Leibniz Formula using Java

Tags: java, math, pi

The Leibniz formula for pi is: pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9... I am trying to write this in Java but am running into a problem where the output is always 4 (which is not the value of pi). I put my code in a java visualizer and it seems that the problem is that when the code falls into the else statement, it is not subtracting (1-denominator) from pi and that is making the prevPi value and the pi value the same which is causing the do/while loop to end. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

My code:

```
public static float piCalculatorLeibniz() {
        float pi = 0;
        int denominator = 1;
        float prevPi = 0;
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (keepGoing == true) {
            prevPi = pi;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                pi += (1/denominator);
            } else {
                pi -= (1/denominator);
            }
            i++;
            denominator += 2;
            if (pi == prevPi) {
                keepGoing = false;
            }
        }
        pi *= 4;
        return pi;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: you really get no true benefit from using float in place of double. Do yourself a favor and use double type instead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what I thought, but actually the difference in performance is significant in this implementation since you're iterating until `pi` reaches a fixed point. Reaching the fixed point when you're using a double takes a lot more iterations and a **LOT** more time. The culprit seems to be the `if (i%2==0)` condition, which I've eliminated from the code in my answer (branch prediction?). Try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. 4 is in fact not the value of Pi.

The problem is that the `denominator` variable is an `int` so `1/denomenator` is `int/int` so the result is `0`. That makes you exit the loop after just one iteration since `pi == prevPi`

Just change the `denominator` type to a double (or float) and you'll get the right answer.

Also, you don't need to write `while(keepGoing == true)`. The variable `keepGoing` is already a boolean, you can write simply `while(keepGoing)`

Edit:

I enjoyed playing with this code, so here's a slightly shorter version that's more accurate due to the use of `double`. It also seems to converge quite a lot faster:

```
double pi = 0, denominator = 1, prevPi = 1;
while (pi != prevPi) {
    prevPi = pi;
    pi += (1 / denominator) - (1 / (denominator + 2));
    denominator += 4;
}
return pi * 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that integer division results in an integer, not a float or double.

`1 / 3` is 0.

To avoid this, you can switch to using a float for the denominator instead of an int.

```
float denominator = 1.0f;
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your, **all** your operands are floating point types. Otherwise your result is an integer.

See [Java Language Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17):

> If the promoted type is float or double, then floating-point arithmetic is performed.

---

Also, on most platforms you can use *double* without any performance penalty, but this is another topic. ;-)